# GetSignaturesForAddress pagination loop

Tags: rpc, getsignaturesforaddress

I ran into a loop when paginating through the GetSignaturesForAddress API. Is this expected? How can we avoid this?

This is the behaviour on a high-level:

1. GetSigs(before=SigA, until=SigC) = [SigB]
2. GetSigs(before=SigB, until=SigC) = [SigA]
3. and so forth

To reproduce:

- Address: cndy3Z4yapfJBmL3ShUp5exZKqR3z33thTzeNMm2gRZ
- SigA: 3TDKVtGkb9Csej17bcC1zP444H15sE4X9q1EeiBGEb3HTeBZ7HicYABcqBSN652YZmanBEHdX1vCCG38s76xQgSt
- SigB: 5hNDbqXihHD6HMRnLVfWBGeVgVgQJEvWbqhVLQ6uSmf4beyT2ugeWnPX2rWxLxiFoZmprHKQtAXLoR5vQ6WqKrRC
- SigC (until): 2yy4e8VX6wijZR2xQCDJh2j5ukMdBeTQw3Hb7vr68adY5zL7XzaBqGweRJUyR7xjoiwAwpKcQGQWgYUdRC6eCz1T

Comment: please add the code